# React Native Styled Components Flatlist Not Showing

Tags: react-native, styled-components

I'm using React Native and Styled Compontents to make a list for a mobile app, but my flatlist isnt showing any return from items in the renderItem prop. It does looks like it returns, because it shows the ItemSeparator content sometimes, but the items don't really render.

The page:

```
import { Container, 
                 Text, 
                 FloatingButton, 
                 List, 
                 ListItem, 
                 ListSeparator, 
                 View } from "../../Styles/index";

import Mapa from '../../Assets/mapa'
import Adicionar from '../../Assets/add_icon'

export default () => {
    
    item = {
        id: 1454532454335,
        Local: "Pedra da galinha choca",
        Regiao: "Quixadá",
        Data: "08/12/2021",
        Hora: "15:00"
    }
    item2 = {
        id: 12131234213,
        Local: "Pedra da galinha choca",
        Regiao: "Quixadá",
        Data: "08/12/2021",
        Hora: "15:00"
    }

    registros = [item, item2]

    const EmptyListMessage = () => {
        return (
            // Quando a lista estiver vazia
            <Container>
                {/* Image + text */}
                <Mapa width="64" height="64" fill="#FFFFFF" />
                <Text padding="20">Não há nenhum registro cadastrado!</Text>
            </Container>
        );
    };

    const ItemSeparatorView = () => {
    return (
      // Flat List Item Separator
      <ListSeparator/>
    );
  };

    const ItemView = ({Local, Regiao, Data, Hora}) => {
        console.log(Data)
    return (
      // Flat List Item
            <View
                style={{
                    flex: 1,
                    flexDirection: "row",
                    backgroundColor: "#000000"
                }}
            >
                <Container flex={3}>
                    <Text size="small" weight="bold" align="left">{Local}</Text>
                    <Text size="small" align="left">{Regiao}</Text>
                </Container>
                <Container>
                    <Text size="small" align='left'>{Data}</Text>
                    <Text size="small" align='left'>{Hora}</Text>
                </Container>
            </View>
    );
  };

    const renderItem = ({item}) => (
        <ItemView 
            Local={item.Local} 
            Regiao={item.Regiao} 
            Data={item.Data} 
            Hora={item.Hora}
        />
    )

    return (
        <Container color="bg">
            <List
                data={registros}
                keyExtractor={item => item.id}
                ItemSeparatorComponent={ItemSeparatorView}
                renderItem={(item) => renderItem(item)}
                ListEmptyComponent={EmptyListMessage}
            />

            <FloatingButton>
                <Adicionar width="48" height="48" />
            </FloatingButton>
        </Container>
    )
}
```

And the styling, fyi:

```
export const Container = styled.View`
    flex: ${(props) => props.flex || '1'};
    width: 100%;
    background: ${(props) => props.color ? theme.colors[props.color] : 'transparent'};
    flex-direction: ${(props) => (props.direction ? 'row' : 'column')};
    justify-content: ${(props) => (props.justify || 'center')};
    padding: ${(props) => props.padding || 0}px;
    padding-top: ${(props) => props.paddingtop || 0}px;
    padding-bottom: ${(props) => props.paddingbottom || 0}px;
    padding-right: ${(props) => props.paddingright || 0}px;
    padding-left: ${(props) => props.paddingleft || 0}px;
    align-items: ${(props) => props.align || 'center'};
    max-width: ${(props) => props.width || '100%'};
    max-height: ${(props) => (props.height ? props.height + 'px' : 'auto')};
    position: ${(props) => props.position || 'relative'};
    top: ${(props) => props.zIndex || 1}px;
`;

export const Text = styled.Text`
    font-size: ${props => props.size ? '17px' : '22px'};
    font-weight: ${props => props.weight ? 'bold' : 'normal'};
    text-align: ${props => props.align || 'center'};
    padding: ${(props) => props.padding || 0}px;
    flex: 1;
    width: 100%;
`;

export const List = styled.FlatList`
    flex: 1;
    padding: 20px;
`;

export const ListItem = styled.TouchableOpacity`
    flex: 1;
    width: 100%;
    flex-direction: row;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
`;

export const ListSeparator = styled.View`
    height: 2px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #B4A982;
`;

export const View = styled.View``;

export const FloatingButton = styled.TouchableOpacity`
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 30px;
    right: 20px;
    border-radius: 50px;
`;`
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I know, you are not using the correct function structure on renderItem; this should work, note the {} around item:

```
<List
   data={registros}
   keyExtractor={item => item.id}
   ItemSeparatorComponent={ItemSeparatorView}
   renderItem={({item}) => renderItem(item)}
   ListEmptyComponent={EmptyListMessage}
/>
```

I don't think you're using typescript, but if you are, in your styles file you should specify the generic type of each item

```
interface GenericType{
    id: number,
    Local: string,
    Regiao: string,
    Data: string,
    Hora: string
};
export const List = styled.FlatList<GenericType>`
    flex: 1;
    padding: 20px;
`;
```